# How to measure expectation values of $Z$ and $X$ on the given states?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

1. Given $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle $ get the expected value of the situation at gate $Z$ for the quantum gate.
2. Given $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle $ get the expected value of the situation at gate $X$ for the quantum gate.

I couldn't find the right answer. Would you help me please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term 'situation'. Could you please explain what it is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: By Situation I mean the calculation in the question.

Comment: @Excalibur welcome to the quantum computing stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new at this. It's hard to get understand.

Comment: for questions like this you should at least show what exactly you find unclear about the exercise, what is your current understanding of the question etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} $ since $|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $|1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} $

Now, we also have that $Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ then note that $Z|0\rangle = |0\rangle$ and $Z|1\rangle = -|1\rangle$. Hence

\begin{align}
\langle \psi | ZZ |\psi \rangle &= \bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\langle 00|+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\langle 01| + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle 11|\bigg)Z Z \bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle \bigg)\\
&=\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\langle 00|+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\langle 01| + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle 11|\bigg) \bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}ZZ|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}ZZ|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}ZZ|11\rangle \bigg)\\
&=\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\langle 00|+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\langle 01| + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle 11|\bigg) \bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|00\rangle - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle \bigg)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{3}\langle 00| 00\rangle - \dfrac{1}{6}\langle 01|01\rangle + \dfrac{1}{2}\langle11|11\rangle = \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Also notice that

\begin{align}
\langle \psi | ZZ |\psi \rangle &= \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & 0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & 0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} =  \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Similarly if we are consider $\langle \psi |XX| \psi\rangle$. Now, just replace $Z$ with $X$ for the computation where $X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and so $X|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ and $X|1\rangle = |0\rangle$.